# Can't move object with grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I've researched this issue, and found people with similar problem. However, the answers are not clear for me.

I'm trying to freely move my objects into X rows and columns. Right now, regardless of what value I put into `column` or `row` my object won't change position, it's always on the top-left corner.

According to other people's answers, empty `rows` and `columns` have zero size. How can I change that?

This is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)

        b = Button(text="This is a button")
        b.grid(row=2, column=3)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 300))
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably [this](https://github.com/Miraj50/Awesome-Tkinter-Apps/tree/master/Movie%20Booking) was something, you were looking for earlier.

Comment: @Miraj50 Thank you very much mate! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, empty rows and columns have zero size. So, without the help of any other options, your widget will be placed at the corner of the window. But with the help of options like `padx`, `pady`, `sticky` and functions like `grid_columnconfigure()` and `grid_rowconfigure()`, you can achieve what you want. As an example, look at this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        b = Button(text="This is a button")
        b.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(20,0))
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 300))
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]